# Execute command in jail

Tags: linux, bash, unix, jail, jail-shell

I'm using [Jailkit](http://olivier.sessink.nl/jailkit/). Is it possible to execute a command inside the jail and get the output (from outside) ? I did a lot of digging in the docs but unable to find anything.

Comment: What you're trying to accomplish would defeat the purpose of `chroot`.

Comment: with basic `chroot` program, that is possible, right ?

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to put an impact outside chroot jail, by executing command inside chroot jail, that's not possible.

Comment: /opt/jail , isn't your jailed root directory? Command impact will be on your 'special root directory'. Not, outside of that. :)

Comment: it is the jailed directory, yes. I want to execute a command inside (from outside) and get the output.

Comment: I then misunderstood your question. But, on my answer I mentioned that if you wants to put impact outside. It appeared confusing :-/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write the output of your jailed command in a non jailed subdirectory you may use the mount command with the option --bind. For example if you want your jailed command to write a file in the non-jailed subdirectory /var/xxx, you should do:

```
mkdir /jail/home/myuser/jailed
mount --bind /var/xxx /jail/home/myuser/jailed
```

Of course, the subdirectory /var/xxx must have write permissions for the user.